Unable to break the inner loop for the second loop to get executed
I am designing a tic-tac-toe game using pygame, but for some reason my inner while loop doesn't break and the second inner loop never gets executed.
def main():
    """Main game loop."""
    font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 48)  # Font for messages
    while True:
        player = "X"  # Starting player
        game_board = Board()  # Create a new game board

        while True:
            for event in pygame.event.get():  # Event handling
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:  # Check for quit event
                    pygame.quit()
                    sys.exit()

                if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:  # Check for mouse click
                    mouse_x, mouse_y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
                    row = mouse_y // CELL_SIZE
                    col = mouse_x // CELL_SIZE

                    # Check for valid input
                    if row in [0, 1, 2] and col in [0, 1, 2]:
                        if game_board.make_move(row, col, player):
                            click_sound.play()  # Play click sound
                            # Draw the player's symbol
                            draw_x(screen, row, col) if player == "X" else draw_o(screen, row, col)

                            # Check for a winner
                            winner = game_board.check_winner()
                            if winner is not None:
                                draw_winning_message(winner)  # Draw the winning message
                                pygame.display.flip()  # Update the display to show the message
                                win_sound.play()
                                winning_animation(winner)  # Call winning animation
                                break  # Exit the inner loop

                            # Check for a draw
                            if game_board.check_draw():
                                draw_sound.play()  # Play draw sound
                                draw_draw_message()  # Draw the draw message
                                pygame.display.flip()  # Update the display to show the message
                                draw_animation()  # Call draw animation
                                break  # Exit the inner loop

                            # Switch players
                            player = "O" if player == "X" else "X"

            # Clear the screen and redraw the grid
            screen.fill(BG_COLOR)
            draw_grid()
            game_board.display_symbols()  # Draw all symbols from the game board
            pygame.display.flip()  # Update the display

        # Now we are either breaking because of a win or a draw
        while True:  # Loop until a valid option is chosen
            screen.fill(BG_COLOR)  # Clear the screen
            game_board.display_symbols()  # Redraw symbols
            
            # Draw options for restarting or exiting
            draw_options()  # Draw the options on the screen
            draw_text("Press R to Restart or E to Exit", font, (255, 255, 255), screen, WIDTH // 2, HEIGHT - 50)
            pygame.display.flip()  # Update the display

            for event in pygame.event.get():  # Handle events
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:  # Check for quit event
                    pygame.quit()
                    sys.exit()
                if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:  # Check for key presses
                    if event.key == pygame.K_r:  # Restart the game
                        break  # Exit the loop to restart the game
                    elif event.key == pygame.K_e:  # Exit the game
                        pygame.quit()  # Ensure Pygame quits properly
                        sys.exit()

The break function itself seems to be working. I tried break at the end of the first inner loop and it worked, but when it is in the if function it doesn't work.

your breaks will only break the innermost loop: the for one. you may find that question relevant: Why does python use 'else' after for and while loops?

The break statement is used to break out of only the inner-most loop in Python (and most other languages).
This is why the below code works:
while True:
   for event in pygame.event.get():
       ...

   break

But this doesn't
while True:
   for event in pygame.event.get():
       ...

       break  # breaks out of only for loop

I would restructure your code by defining another boolean variable to check whether you need to move on to the next piece of code or not.
continue_loop = True

while continue_loop:
   for event in pygame.event.get():
       if condition:
          ...
          continue_loop = False
          break
       
       ...


It seems the break function was only breaking for loop and when the break was used for while loop it just completely skipped all the code below, so I used a variable to initiate break for the while loop and when the variable is true only then will the while loop break
def main():
font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 20)
while True:
    # Initialize game variables
    player = "X"
    game_board = Board()
    restart_game, option = False, False

    while True:  # Game loop
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                mouse_x, mouse_y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
                row, col = mouse_y // CELL_SIZE, mouse_x // CELL_SIZE

                if row in [0, 1, 2] and col in [0, 1, 2]:
                    if game_board.make_move(row, col, player):
                        click_sound.play()
                        draw_x(screen, row, col) if player == "X" else draw_o(screen, row, col)

                        winner = game_board.check_winner()
                        if winner:
                            draw_winning_message(winner)
                            pygame.display.flip()
                            win_sound.play()
                            winning_animation(winner)
                            option = True
                            break

                        if game_board.check_draw():
                            draw_sound.play()
                            draw_draw_message()
                            pygame.display.flip()
                            draw_animation()
                            option = True
                            break

                        player = "O" if player == "X" else "X"

        # Update screen after each event
        screen.fill(BG_COLOR)
        draw_grid()
        game_board.display_symbols()
        pygame.display.flip()
        if option:
            break

    # Restart or exit loop after game ends
    while True:
        screen.fill(BG_COLOR)
        draw_options()
        draw_text("Press R to Restart or E to Exit", font, (255, 255, 255), screen, WIDTH // 2, HEIGHT - 50)
        pygame.display.flip()

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
            if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                if event.key == pygame.K_e:
                    pygame.quit()
                    sys.exit()
                elif event.key == pygame.K_r:
                    restart_game = True
                    break
        if restart_game:
            break

